# Selenium WebDriver(3.3.1.JAR) with WIN10 64bit, IE11

Tags: selenium-webdriver, internet-explorer-11, nosuchelementexception

-I m using Selenium webdriver(3.3.1.Jar) with TestNG in Win10 x64bit, IE11 and my code is working for other broswers(Chrome, Firefox) except IE11.
-I made protected security mode to same unchecked
-set JAVA_HOME & Path in Env variables
-Changed Registry setting for IE11.
-Made Zoom level 100%
-Tried with other old selenium server jar as well as other old IEdriverserver.exe
Here is what i m experiencing
-button click doesn't work
-execution slow
-can't find many elements which other broswers easily run
Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try below solution:
(For IE 11 only, you will need to set a registry entry on the target computer so that the driver can maintain a connection to the instance of Internet Explorer it creates.

For 32-bit Windows installations, the key you must examine in the registry editor is

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE.
```

For 64-bit Windows installations, the key is

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main\FeatureControl\FEATURE_BFCACHE
```

Please note that the FEATURE_BFCACHE subkey may or may not be present, and should be created if it is not present. Inside this key, create a DWORD value named iexplore.exe with the value of 0.)